# Add scripts on custom post add/edit pages Not Working

Tags: posts, javascript, html

im Trying to Add scripts on custom post add/edit pages but Not Working

PHP Code ,(it's working and Get Js Code)

```
if(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin/post-new.php') || strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin/page-new.php')) {
wp_enqueue_script('myscript', 'http://exemple.com/wp-content/themes/theme/js/rt_api.js');
```

The Probleme is Js Code Not Give Result :

[Check my Js and HTMl Code](http://jsfiddle.net/9ES3N/)

Comment: I think you're trying to add the files in the admin area. If I am not wrong, please check out: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts Cheers!

Comment: IS the script being loaded?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things you'll want to do to make you include work and in generally better. Here is the complete code:

```
function my_theme_enqueue_admin_scripts() {
    $screen = get_current_screen(); // This is how we will check what page we are on
    if ( in_array( $screen->id, array( 'post', 'page') ) && $screen->action == 'add' ) {
        // Use get_template_directory_uri so we don't need to hardcode the URL to our theme folder
        wp_enqueue_script('myscript', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/rt_api.js');
    }
}
// This action will call your function at the right time to enqueue your script for the admin area
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_admin_scripts' );
```

- I used the [hook `admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) to call our function to enqueue the script at the correct time for the admin area
- I use the [`$screen` object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) which WordPress creates for the admin area to signal what page is currently being viewed. It has a bunch of attributes on it. In our case, I'm checking `$screen->id` for if it is `'post'` or `'page'`, and `$screen->action` for if it is `'add'`.
- Finally, I use [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) to get the URL to the theme folder. This way we can use our theme on any WordPress setup without breaking the URL.

**Using jQuery in Your Script**

When you use jQuery in your scripts, you can't use the `$` right off the bat as the version of jQuery included with WordPress disables the `$` shorthand for `jQuery`. This is because back in the day it is common for multiple Javascript libraries to use `$`.

You have two options in your Javascript to use jQuery.

The first is to use `jQuery` instead of `$`:

```
jQuery('#my-id').on('click', function() {} );
```

The second is to wrap the code of your script in a self-calling function. You'll pass `jQuery` in as a parameter and then we will name the argument `$`:

```
(function( $ ) {
    // your code here
})( jQuery );
```

**Debugging Tips**

- make sure that your 'myscript' is printed out by viewing the page source
- check that the URL printed is correct (it is easy to have a typo)
- make sure the Javascript is not without errors
- is another script also using the handle `myscript` creating a conflict